# How to display lowercase and uppercase letters

Tags: assembly

i'm having difficulties working on a program that requires me to display lowercase letters and their uppercase letters using interrupts. The whole thing should display one lower and uppercase letter per line. I tried everything and nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What processor, what OS, etc.

Comment: _"I tried everything and nothing worked"_ isn't particularly informative. You need to explain exactly what you tried and in what way it didn't work.

Comment: i added an example of what i did that doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to convert a letter to uppercase is:

```
and al, 11011111b
;Replace al by the register where the letter is stored.
```

and to convert a letter to lowercase:

```
or al, 00100000b
```

This code don't works for special characters (french accents, umlauts, etc)

Answer (score 0):

One part of the answer is hidden in each ASCII table that shows the ASCII numbers and here is a link of one of them: http://www.asciitable.com/
For to print an ASCII to the screen we can use this bios software interrupt: http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0129.HTM

Answer (score 0):

ok so heres what i tried

org 100h

back:

mov al,61h

mov bl,al

mov ah,0eh

int 10h

mov al,20h              ;print a space

int 10h

sub bl,20h

mov al,bl

int 10h                 ;display upper case

mov al,0Dh              ;Carriage return

int 10h

mov al,0Ah              ;Line feed

int 10h

mov al,26

je reset

cmp al,0

jz stop

jmp back

reset:
sub al,26

mov al,61h

jmp back

stop:
hlt

but it only gave my a A all the way

Comment: There's a few logic errors I can see here. You have this sequence: `mov al,26` `je reset` `cmp al,0` `jz stop` `jmp back`. Your code has no jumps into this sequence, so all 5 of those are always run, in that order. Since `MOV` doesn't alter the flags on this CPU, it's not clear what the `je reset` is conditional on. I'm guessing something that happens during `int 10h` but usually that would be the carry flag. And since you just moved 26 into `al`, your `cmp al,0 jz stop` will never jump to `stop`.